# Reading coordinates from dxf file c#

Tags: c#, dxf

I am writing a code in c# to read the point coordinates from a dxf file. I am basically reading line by line of dxf file and checking against a condition like `if( i == "AcdbLine")` write the coordinates of the point into a file.

```
AcDbLine
10
0.0
20
0.0
 30
0.0
 11
700.0
 21
0.0
 31
0.0
  0
LINE
```

This writes the coordinates as (0,0,0) (700,0,0).

My issue right now is to ignore `AcDbLine` when it is found within a **block**. I want to write a logic which ignores any `AcDbline` and its corresponding points when it falls within the block of `AcDbBlockBegin` and `AcDbBlockEnd`.

```
AcDbBlockBegin
  2
*U1
 70
     1
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  3
*U1
  1

  0
LINE
  5
3F0
330
3E9
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbLine
 10
-47.22702216883923
 20
-0.0131059296418084
 30
0.0
 11
-19.82207380431916
 21
-0.0131059296418084
 31
0.0
  0
LINE
  5
3F1
330
3E9
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbLine
 10
22.19765948514734
 20
0.0131059296418101
 30
0.0
 11
47.22702216883923
 21
0.0131059296418101
 31
0.0
  0
ENDBLK
  5
3EB
330
3E9
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbBlockEnd
```

Sorry for the long code and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been writing text parser for over 40 years.  If I can't do it nobody can.  Try code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            FIND_BLOCK,
            GET_ACDB_LINE,
            ACD_BLOCK
        }
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            State state = State.FIND_BLOCK;
            int lineRow = 0;
            Line newLine = new Line();
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_BLOCK :
                            switch (inputLine)
                            {
                                case "AcDbBlockBegin" :
                                    state = State.ACD_BLOCK;
                                    break;
                                case "AcDbLine":
                                    state = State.GET_ACDB_LINE;
                                    lineRow = 0;
                                    newLine = new Line();
                                    Line.lines.Add(newLine);
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case State.ACD_BLOCK :
                            if (inputLine == "AcDbBlockEnd")
                            {
                                state = State.FIND_BLOCK;
                            }
                            break;

                        case State.GET_ACDB_LINE :
                            if (inputLine == "LINE")
                            {
                                state = State.FIND_BLOCK;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                switch (++lineRow)
                                {
                                    case 2:
                                        newLine.xLoc = double.Parse(inputLine);
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        newLine.yLoc = double.Parse(inputLine);
                                        break;
                                    case 6:
                                        newLine.zLoc = double.Parse(inputLine);
                                        break;
                                    case 8:
                                        newLine.xVal = double.Parse(inputLine);
                                        break;
                                    case 10:
                                        newLine.yVal = double.Parse(inputLine);
                                        break;
                                    case 12:
                                        newLine.zVal = double.Parse(inputLine);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        public class Line
        {
            public static List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
            public double xLoc { get; set; }
            public double xVal { get; set; }
            public double yLoc { get; set; }
            public double yVal { get; set; }
            public double zLoc { get; set; }
            public double zVal { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with a similar question ?

Comment: Do you have sample of input file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285763/how-to-extract-all-coordinates-from-a-dxf-file