# How to extract all coordinates from a dxf file

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, autocad

Ive got a dxf file https://filebin.net/7l8izrv2js7doicc/5holes-8x8.dxf?t=9ro7k928 (download and name extension as .dxf)
Im able to parse it for lines and all but I want to extract all coordinates now.
The purpose is that if I get all the coordinates then Id be able to create a bounding box for all these coordinates.
Since the drawing has curves and lines I dont know how to do it for curves etc.

===MY PARTIAL CODE TO DISPLAY LINES & pull out start & end point of lines====

```
flist=open("test2.dxf")

#fil.readlines()
# entityflist = open("filename.txt").readlines()
lst=[]

parsing = False
for line in flist:
    #print ("==================")
    if line.startswith("ENDSEC"):
        parsing = False
    if parsing:
        #print (line)
        lst.append(line)
        #Do stuff with data 
    if line.startswith("LINE"):
        parsing = True
        #print ("LINE")

# lines coordinates list
ts=(''.join(lst).split('LINE'))

#print out all the point coordinates of lines start & end
# i.e. 2 coordinate pairs for each line
for i in ts:
    print ((i.split()[19],i.split()[21]))
    print ((i.split()[15],i.split()[17]))
```

Comment: Link is broken.....

Comment: https://filebin.net/7l8izrv2js7doicc/5holes-8x8.dxf?t=9ro7k928

Answer (score 1):

Your link doesn't work but rather post a few lines of the file to show the structure, as it's bad practice to request people downloading huge files.

Looks like there is a library for handling dxf files called `ezdxf`.
[Here is a link](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/tutorials/getting_data.html) to their guide on how to extract data from a dxf file

Answer (score 0):

He is a good start..  I did Headers, Classes, Entities,and Tables (most of the codes).

Part 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace DXF_Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            SECTION_START,
            SECTION_CONTINUE,
            EOF,
            NONE
        }
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            State state = State.SECTION_START;
            Section section = new Section(); 
            string line = "";
            Result result = null;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while ((state != State.EOF) && (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                lineCount++;
                //if (line.Length > 0)
                //{
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.SECTION_START:
                            //section = new Section();
                            //section.AddSection();
                            result = section.Parse(line);
                            if (result.status != "OK") Error(lineCount, line, result);
                            state = State.SECTION_CONTINUE;
                            break;

                        case State.SECTION_CONTINUE:
                            if (line == "EOF")
                            {
                                state = State.EOF;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result = section.Parse(line);
                                switch (result.status)
                                {
                                    case "OK":
                                        break;
                                   case "ENDSEC":
                                        state = State.SECTION_START;
                                        section.row = 1;
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        Error(lineCount, line, result);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                //}
            }
            Console.Write("Press Return");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Error(int lineCount, string line, Result error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : {0}, Line Number : {1}, Line : {2}", error.message, lineCount, line);
        }

    }
    public class Result
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
    public enum GROUP_CODE
    {
        ENTITY_TYPE = 0,
        PRIMARY_TEXT_VALUE = 1,
        NAME = 2,
        TEXT = 3,
        ENTITY_HANDLE = 5,
        LINE_TYPE = 6,
        TEXT_STYLE_NAME = 7,
        LAYER_NAME = 8,
        DXF = 9,
        PRIMARY_POINT = 10,
        PRIMARY_POINT_CORNER = 11,
        PRIMARY_POINT_2 = 12,
        PRIMARY_POINT_3 = 13,
        PRIMARY_POINT_4 = 14,
        PRIMARY_POINT_5 = 15,
        PRIMARY_POINT_6 = 16,
        PRIMARY_POINT_7 = 17,
        PRIMARY_POINT_8 = 18,
        PRIMARY_POINT_9 = 19,
        Y_VALUE = 20,
        Y_VALUE_CORNER = 21,
        Y_VALUE_2 = 22,
        Y_VALUE_3 = 23,
        Y_VALUE_4 = 24,
        Y_VALUE_5 = 25,
        Y_VALUE_6 = 26,
        Y_VALUE_7 = 27,
        Y_VALUE_8 = 28,
        Y_VALUE_9 = 29,
        Z_VALUE = 30,
        Z_VALUE_CORNER = 31,
        Z_VALUE_2 = 32,
        Z_VALUE_3 = 33,
        Z_VALUE_4 = 34,
        Z_VALUE_5 = 35,
        Z_VALUE_6 = 36,
        Z_VALUE_7 = 37,
        Z_VALUE_8 = 38,
        Z_VALUE_9 = 39,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION = 40,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_1 = 41,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_2 = 42,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_3 = 43,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_4 = 44,
        LINE_TYPE_SCALE = 48,
        ANGLE = 50,
        ANGLE_1 = 51,
        COLOR_NUMBER = 62,
        NOT_IN_SPECIFICATION = 65,
        INT_VALUE = 70,
        INT_VALUE_1 = 71,
        INT_VALUE_2 = 72,
        INT_VALUE_3 = 73,
        INT_VALUE_4 = 74,
        INT_VALUE_5 = 75,
        INT_VALUE_6 = 76,
        INT_VALUE_7 = 77,
        INT_VALUE_8 = 78,
        INT_VALUE_9 = 79,
        PROXY_CAPABILITY_FLAG = 90,
        SUBCLASS_MARKER = 100,
        UCF_X = 110,
        UCF_X1 = 111,
        UCF_X2 = 112,
        UCF_Y = 120,
        UCF_Y1 = 121,
        UCF_Y2 = 122,
        UCF_Z = 130,
        UCF_Z1 = 131,
        UCF_Z2 = 132,

        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT = 140,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_1 = 141,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_2 = 142,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_3 = 143,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_4 = 144,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_5 = 145,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_6 = 146,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_7 = 147,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_8 = 148,
        DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_9 = 149,


        INSTANCE_COUNT = 91,
        INT_16 = 280,
        INT_16_1 = 281,
        BOOLEAN = 290,
        SOFT_POINTER_HANDLE = 330,
        HARD_POINTER_HANDLE_7 = 347,
        LINE_WEIGHT = 370,
        PLOT_STYLE =380
    }
    public enum READ_STATE
    {
        GET_CREATE_SECTION,
        GET_OBJECT_TYPE,
        GET_OBJECT,
        GET_GROUP_CODE,
        GET_LAYER,
        GET_LAYER_NAME,
        GET_SECTION_DATA,
        GET_VARIABLE_NAME,
        GET_VARIABLE_TYPE,
        GET_VARIABLE_VALUES,
        NONE
    }
    public class Section
    {
        public static List<Section> sections = new List<Section>();
        GROUP_CODE currentGroupCode { get; set; }
        Section currentSection { get; set; }
        public int row = 1;
        string sectionName { get; set; }
        READ_STATE readState = READ_STATE.NONE;

        public int numberValues { get; set; }
        public int valueCounter = 0;

        public void AddSection()
        {
             sections.Add(this);
        }
        public Result Parse(string line)
        {
            Result result = new Result() { status = "OK" };
            int number = 0;

            switch (row)
            {
                case 1:
                    number = int.Parse(line);
                    if (number != (int)GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_TYPE)
                    {
                        result.status = "ERROR";
                        result.message = "Bad Section Code";
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    switch (line)
                    {
                        case "SECTION" :
                            break;
                        case "EOF" :
                            result.status = "EOF";
                            break;
                        default :
                            result.status = "ERROR";
                            result.message = "Expecting Section";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    number = int.Parse(line);
                    if (number != (int)GROUP_CODE.NAME)
                    {
                        result.status = "ERROR";
                        result.message = "Bad Group Code";
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sectionName = line;
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_CREATE_SECTION;
                    break;

                default:
                    if (readState == READ_STATE.GET_CREATE_SECTION)
                    {
                        switch (sectionName)
                        {
                            case "HEADER":
                                currentSection = new Header();
                                break;
                            case "ENTITIES":
                                currentSection = new Entities();
                                break;
                            case "CLASSES":
                                currentSection = new Class();
                                break;
                            case "TABLES":
                                currentSection = new Table();
                                break;
                            default :
                                break;
                        }
                        currentSection.sectionName = sectionName;
                        Section.sections.Add(currentSection);
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_SECTION_DATA;
                    }
                    switch (sectionName)
                    {
                        case "HEADER":
                            result = ((Header)currentSection).HeaderParse(line);
                            break;
                        case "ENTITIES":
                            result = ((Entities)currentSection).EntityParse(line);
                            break;
                        case "CLASSES":
                            result = ((Class)currentSection).ClassParse(line);
                            break;
                       case "TABLES":
                            result = ((Table)currentSection).TableParse(line);
                            break;
                           default :
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

            }
            row++;

            return result;
        }
    }
    public class Header : Section
    {
        public GROUP_CODE groupCode { get; set; }

        GROUP_CODE currentGroupCode { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, DXF_Header_Variable> dictHeaderVariables;
        DXF_Header_Variable currentVariable = null;
        READ_STATE readState = READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE;

        public Result HeaderParse(string line)
        {

            Result result = new Result() { status = "OK" };
            switch (readState)
            {
                case READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE:
                    currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME:
                    if (line == "ENDSEC")
                    {
                        result.status = line;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (dictHeaderVariables == null) dictHeaderVariables = new Dictionary<string, DXF_Header_Variable>();
                        currentVariable = new DXF_Header_Variable();
                        dictHeaderVariables.Add(line, currentVariable);
                        currentVariable.name = line;
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                    }
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE:
                    groupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    switch (groupCode)
                    {
                        case GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_TYPE :
                            readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                            break;
                        case GROUP_CODE.DXF:
                            readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                            break;
                        default:
                            readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES:
                     switch (groupCode)
                     {
                         case GROUP_CODE.ANGLE:
                             currentVariable.angle = double.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.BOOLEAN :
                             currentVariable.logic = (line == "0")? false : true;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.COLOR_NUMBER:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION:
                             currentVariable.primaryPoint = double.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_HANDLE:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.HARD_POINTER_HANDLE_7:
                             currentVariable.text = line;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.INT_16:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.LINE_TYPE:
                             currentVariable.text = line;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.LAYER_NAME:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.LINE_WEIGHT:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.NAME:
                             currentVariable.text = line;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.PLOT_STYLE:
                             currentVariable.intValue = int.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT:
                             currentVariable.primaryPoint = double.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_TEXT_VALUE:
                             currentVariable.primaryTextValue = line;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.TEXT:
                             currentVariable.text = line;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.TEXT_STYLE_NAME:
                             currentVariable.text = line;
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE:
                             currentVariable.y = double.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE:
                             currentVariable.z = double.Parse(line);
                             break;
                         default :
                             break;
                     }
                     readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                     break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
    public class DXF_Header_Variable
    {
        public double angle { get; set; }
        public double primaryPoint { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double z { get; set; }
        public string primaryTextValue { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int intValue { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public Boolean logic { get; set; }
    }
    public class Entities : Section
    {
        public GROUP_CODE groupCode { get; set; }
        GROUP_CODE currentGroupCode { get; set; }
        public List<Entity> entities;
        Entity currentEntity = null;
        READ_STATE readState = READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE;

        public Result EntityParse(string line)
        {

            Result result = new Result() { status = "OK" };
            switch (readState)
            {
                case READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE:
                    currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME:
                    if (line == "ENDSEC")
                    {
                        result.status = line;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (entities == null) entities = new List<Entity>();
                        currentEntity = new Entity();
                        entities.Add(currentEntity);
                        currentEntity.name = line;
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_LAYER;
                    }
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_LAYER:
                    groupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_LAYER_NAME;
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_LAYER_NAME:
                    currentEntity.layerName = int.Parse(line);
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE:
                    groupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    if (groupCode == GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_TYPE)
                    {
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES;
                    }
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES:
                    double value = double.Parse(line);
                    switch (groupCode)
                    {
                        case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT :
                            currentEntity.primaryPoint = value;
                            break;
                        case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE:
                            currentEntity.y = value;
                            break;
                        case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE:
                            currentEntity.z = value;
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_CORNER :
                            currentEntity.primaryPoint = value;
                            break;
                        case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_CORNER :
                            currentEntity.yCorner = value;
                            break;
                        case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_CORNER:
                            currentEntity.zCorner = value;
                            break;
                    }

                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public double primaryPoint { get; set; }
        public double y { get; set; }
        public double z { get; set; }
        public double primaryPointCorner { get; set; }
        public double yCorner { get; set; }
        public double zCorner { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int layerName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Class : Section
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Class_Type> dictClassVariables;
        Class_Type currentClass = null;
        GROUP_CODE currentGroupCode { get; set; }
        string className { get; set; }
        READ_STATE readState = READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE;

        public Result ClassParse(string line)
        {

            Result result = new Result() { status = "OK" };
            switch (readState)
            {
                case READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE:
                    currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME:
                    if (line == "ENDSEC")
                    {
                        result.status = line;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                    }
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE:
                    currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                    switch (currentGroupCode)
                    {
                        case GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_TYPE:
                            readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                            break;
                        default:
                            readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES:
                    switch (currentGroupCode)
                    {
                        case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_TEXT_VALUE :
                            if (dictClassVariables == null) dictClassVariables = new Dictionary<string,Class_Type>();
                            currentClass = new Class_Type();
                            dictClassVariables.Add(line, currentClass);
                            currentClass.dxfName = line;
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.NAME:
                            currentClass.className = line;
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.TEXT:
                            currentClass.applicationName = line;
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.PROXY_CAPABILITY_FLAG:
                            currentClass.proxyCapabilityFlag  = uint.Parse(line);
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.INSTANCE_COUNT:
                            currentClass.instance = int.Parse(line);
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.INT_16:
                            currentClass.wasAProxyFlag = (line == "0") ? false : true;
                            break;

                        case GROUP_CODE.INT_16_1:
                            currentClass.isAnEntityFlag = (line == "0") ? false : true;
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
    public class Class_Type
    {
        public string dxfName { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public string applicationName { get; set; }
        public uint proxyCapabilityFlag { get; set; }
        public int instance { get; set; }
        public Boolean wasAProxyFlag { get; set; }
        public Boolean isAnEntityFlag { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: thanks but I dont know Java :-) , I can deal with python only

Answer (score 0):

Part2

```
        public class Table : Section
        {
            public List<VPort> vPorts;
            VPort currentVPort = null;
            GROUP_CODE currentGroupCode { get; set; }
            string vPortName { get; set; }
            READ_STATE readState = READ_STATE.GET_OBJECT_TYPE;

            public Result TableParse(string line)
            {

                Result result = new Result() { status = "OK" };
                switch (readState)
                {
                    case READ_STATE.GET_OBJECT_TYPE :
                        currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_OBJECT;
                        break;
                    case READ_STATE.GET_OBJECT :
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE;
                        break;
                    case READ_STATE.GET_GROUP_CODE:
                        currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                        break;
                    case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME:
                        if (line == "ENDSEC")
                        {
                            result.status = line;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (currentVPort == null) currentVPort = new VPort();
                            currentVPort.tableName = line;
                            readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                        }
                        break;
                    case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE:
                        currentGroupCode = (GROUP_CODE)Enum.Parse(typeof(GROUP_CODE), line);
                        switch (currentGroupCode)
                        {
                            case GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_TYPE:
                                readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_NAME;
                                break;
                            default:
                                readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_VALUES:
                        switch (currentGroupCode)
                        {
                            case GROUP_CODE.ANGLE:
                                currentVPort.angle = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.ANGLE_1:
                                currentVPort.angle1 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecission = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_1:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecission1 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_2:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecission2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_3:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecission3 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_4:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecission4 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_1:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint1 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_2:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_3:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint3 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_4:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint4 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_5:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint5 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_6:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint6 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_7:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint7 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_8:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint8 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.DOUBLE_PRECISION_POINT_9:
                                currentVPort.doublePrecissionPoint9 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.ENTITY_HANDLE:
                                currentVPort.handle = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE:
                                currentVPort.maxEntries = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_1 :
                                currentVPort.integer_1 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_2:
                                currentVPort.integer_2 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_3:
                                currentVPort.integer_3 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_4:
                                currentVPort.integer_4 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_5:
                                currentVPort.integer_5 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_6:
                                currentVPort.integer_6 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_7:
                                currentVPort.integer_7 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_8:
                                currentVPort.integer_8 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_VALUE_9:
                                currentVPort.integer_9 = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.INT_16_1:
                                currentVPort.int16_1= int.Parse(line);
                                break;

                            case GROUP_CODE.NAME:
                                currentVPort.tableName = line;
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.SOFT_POINTER_HANDLE:
                                currentVPort.softPointerHandle = int.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.SUBCLASS_MARKER:
                                if (currentVPort.subclassMarkers == null) currentVPort.subclassMarkers = new List<string>();
                                currentVPort.subclassMarkers.Add(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_CORNER:
                                currentVPort.primaryPointCorner = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_2:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_3:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint3 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_4:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint4 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_5:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint5 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_6:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint6 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_7:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint7 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_8:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint8 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.PRIMARY_POINT_9:
                                currentVPort.primaryPoint9 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_X:
                                currentVPort.ucf_x = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_X1:
                                currentVPort.ucf_x1 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_X2:
                                currentVPort.ucf_x2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_Y:
                                currentVPort.ucf_y = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_Y1:
                                currentVPort.ucf_y1 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_Y2:
                                currentVPort.ucf_y2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_Z:
                                currentVPort.ucf_z = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_Z1:
                                currentVPort.ucf_z1 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.UCF_Z2:
                                currentVPort.ucf_z2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE:
                                currentVPort.y = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_CORNER:
                                currentVPort.yCorner = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_2:
                                currentVPort.y2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_3:
                                currentVPort.y3= double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_4:
                                currentVPort.y4 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_5:
                                currentVPort.y5 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_6:
                                currentVPort.y6 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_7:
                                currentVPort.y7 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_8:
                                currentVPort.y8 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Y_VALUE_9:
                                currentVPort.y9 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE:
                                currentVPort.z = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_CORNER:
                                currentVPort.zCorner = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_2:
                                currentVPort.z2 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_3:
                                currentVPort.z3 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_4:
                                currentVPort.z4 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_5:
                                currentVPort.z5 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_6:
                                currentVPort.z6 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_7:
                                currentVPort.z7 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_8:
                                currentVPort.z8 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            case GROUP_CODE.Z_VALUE_9:
                                currentVPort.z9 = double.Parse(line);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        readState = READ_STATE.GET_VARIABLE_TYPE;
                        break;

                }

                return result;
            }
        }
        public class VPort
        {
            public string dxfName { get; set; }
            public string tableName { get; set; }
            public int handle { get; set; }
            public int softPointerHandle { get; set; }
            public List<string>subclassMarkers { get; set; }
            public int maxEntries { get; set; }

            public double doublePrecission { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecission1 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecission2 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecission3 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecission4 { get; set; }

            public double doublePrecissionPoint { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint1 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint2 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint3 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint4 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint5 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint6 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint7 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint8 { get; set; }
            public double doublePrecissionPoint9 { get; set; }

            public int integer_1 { get; set; }
            public int integer_2 { get; set; }
            public int integer_3 { get; set; }
            public int integer_4 { get; set; }
            public int integer_5 { get; set; }
            public int integer_6 { get; set; }
            public int integer_7 { get; set; }
            public int integer_8 { get; set; }
            public int integer_9 { get; set; }

            public int int16_1 { get; set; }
     

            public double angle { get; set; }
            public double angle1 { get; set; }

            public double primaryPoint { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint1 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint2 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint3 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint4 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint5 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint6 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint7 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint8 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPoint9 { get; set; }
            public double primaryPointCorner { get; set; }

            public double ucf_x { get; set; }
            public double ucf_x1 { get; set; }
            public double ucf_x2 { get; set; }
            public double ucf_y { get; set; }
            public double ucf_y1 { get; set; }
            public double ucf_y2 { get; set; }
            public double ucf_z { get; set; }
            public double ucf_z1 { get; set; }
            public double ucf_z2 { get; set; }


            public double y { get; set; }
            public double yCorner { get; set; }
            public double y2 { get; set; }
            public double y3 { get; set; }
            public double y4 { get; set; }
            public double y5 { get; set; }
            public double y6 { get; set; }
            public double y7 { get; set; }
            public double y8 { get; set; }
            public double y9 { get; set; }
            public double z { get; set; }
            public double zCorner { get; set; }
            public double z2 { get; set; }
            public double z3 { get; set; }
            public double z4 { get; set; }
            public double z5 { get; set; }
            public double z6 { get; set; }
            public double z7 { get; set; }
            public double z8 { get; set; }
            public double z9 { get; set; }

        }
    }
```